# Would inserts and updates fire a delete trigger?

Tags: t-sql

I am in the unfortunate situation of needing to add triggers to a table to track changes to a legacy system. I have insert, update, and delete triggers on TABLE_A each one of them writes the values of two columns to a TABLE_B, and a bit flag that is set to 1 if populated by the delete trigger.

Every entry in TABLE_B shows up twice. An insert crates two rows, and update creates two rows (we believe), and a delete creates an insert and then a delete.

Is the legacy application doing this, or is SQL doing it?

EDIT (adding more detail):

body of triggers:

.. after delete

```
INSERT INTO TableB(col1, isdelete) SELECT col1, 1 from DELETED
```

.. after insert

```
INSERT INTO TableB(col1, isdelete) SELECT col1, 0 from INSERTED
```

.. after update

```
INSERT INTO TableB(col1, isdelete) SELECT col1, 0 from DELETED
```

I have tried profiler, and do not see any duplicate statements being executed.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you without some additional information: the trigger code, and a simple before/after example of the table data would probably be helpful.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).  It can help you pin down what the application is doing.

Comment: Added more detail... to question

Comment: Have you checked whether you have more triggers on the table than you expect?  I just scripted out your scenario, and I got 1 row per DM operation.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the application is changing the data again when it sees the operations on its data.

It's also possible that triggers exist elsewhere - is there any possiblity that there is a trigger on TableB that is creating extra rows?

More detail would be needed to address the question more fully.